# why can not remove last row in sql by using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I can't remove last row in my table. I must add another row then delete previous row.  This is my code (C# 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2)

```
private void btndelete1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this," Are you sure to delete this record ? ", "Attention", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count > 1 && dataGridViewX1.SelectedRows[0].Index != dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    SqlCommand delcmd = new SqlCommand();
                    delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM CustumerTB WHERE CID=   "+dataGridViewX1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";
                    conn.Open();
                    delcmd.Connection = conn;
                    delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataGridViewX1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridViewX1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                    conn.Close();
                }
                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using sql server, why is mysql tagged? please do not tag irrelevant products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count > 1 && dataGridViewX1.SelectedRows[0].Index != dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count - 1)
```

...

in other words:
if the datagridview contains more than one row

AND

if the last row is not selected...

what do you expect from this?

Comment: if (dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count > 0 && dataGridViewX1.SelectedRows[0].Index != -1 )

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the last row because of your `if` statement:

```
if (dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count > 1 && dataGridViewX1.SelectedRows[0].Index != dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count - 1)
```

The first condition the `if` statement tests is whether `dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count` is greater than 1.  So if you have only one row, this test fails, the `if` statement is false and the delete command is never run.  As soon as you add a new run, the row count is greater than 1 and you can delete a row again.